# c pointer is incrementing in reverse way when i execute this code in linux

Tags: c

I wrote a simple c program like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int a=10;
int *p;int **q;
p=&a,q=&p;
printf("size of p %d\n",sizeof(p));
printf("%d\t%d\n",p,q);
printf("%d\t%d",++p,++q);
}
```

output is like this

```
size of p 8
55611340        55611320
55611344        55611328
```

if i am execcuting same binary once more i am getting like this

```
size of p 8
-385904884      -385904904
-385904880      -385904896
```

why output is varying in reverse way second time . O/p is randomly varying in reverse way every time. Can any please tell me why this one happens

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. `"%d"` is not for printing pointers.

Comment: @juanchopanza: and `sizeof()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Comment: There's no reverse here. `-385904884 + 4` = `-385904880`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%d` format specifier is for printing signed integers, not pointers.  Using the incorrect format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To properly print pointers, use the `%p` format specifier and cast the pointer in question to `void *` (one of the rare time casting to/from `void *` is required).

```
printf("%p\t%p\n", (void *)p, (void *)q);
printf("%p\t%p", (void *)(++p), (void *)(++q));
```

Also, use the `%zu` format specifier for printing a `size_t` (which the `sizeof` operator returns).

```
printf("size of p %zu\n",sizeof(p));
```

Answer (score 2):

Im going to try answer the question I think you are asking which is this:

> Why are the numbers not what I expect?

I got some deeper insight into your program by modifying it thus:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int a=10;
int *p;int **q;
p=&a,q=&p;
printf("size of p %d\n",sizeof(p));
printf("size of q %d\n", sizeof(q));
printf("size of int %d\n", sizeof(int));
printf("size of int* %d\n", sizeof(int*));
printf("size of int** %d\n", sizeof(int**));
printf("%d\t%d\n",p,q);
printf("%d\t%d",++p,++q);
}
```

I get the following results:

```
size of p 8
size of q 8
size of int 4
size of int* 8
size of int** 8
1741631236  1741631240
1741631240  1741631248
```

The interpretation of this is that p is a pointer to an int, which is 4 bytes in size. When you increment a pointer-to-int the pointer gets incremented by 4. However q is a pointer-to-pointer. Now, a pointer is 8 bytes in size, so when you increment a pointer-to-pointer, it gets incremented by 8.

This is exactly what we see in your example output as well: the difference between p and q, before and after the increment, is 4 and 8 respectively.

Comment: Thanks . your answer is clear , i have one small doubt when we use           int **q --> what this int is actually refer to ?

Comment: Thanks . your answer is clear , i have one small doubt when we use           int *p--> when i increment p it incements by four,                   if char *p --> when i increment p it increments by one .                         so My actual doubt is                                                                             int **q --> when q stores the addrees of p . If i increment q it increments by 8. what exactly "int/char " stands in double pointer  (int/char **q).                                                                                                 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You created 64 bit app so the size of pointer is 8 bytes

All pointer is ok, It will be clear, if you display pointer value properly (all values will be in hexadecimal):

**the only correct way:**

```
printf("%p\t%p\n",p,q);
printf("%p\t%p",++p,++q);
```

or you may use (do not protected from undefined behavior)

```
printf("%016llx\t%016llx\n",p,q);
printf("%016llx\t%016llx",++p,++q);
```

or simple unsigned values

```
printf("%llu\t%llu\n",p,q);
printf("%llu\t%llu",++p,++q);
```

Reversed values is because you display integer values (signed), if you display unsigned value or hexadecimal integer the results will be displayed properly.

Comment: Although you are correct in practice, there are no guarantees that this code will work portably. `%p` is the correct conversion specifier for printing pointers. (I didn't down vote)

Comment: @Lundin I have updated my post now its ok)) Thank you for pointing me!))

Comment: Well, it is not the most correct way, it is the only correct way :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like % d is used for printing address in code.%d is used for integer variable 
 so it taking has

INT_MIN Minimum value for a variable of type int.   –2147483648

INT_MAX Maximum value for a variable of type int.   2147483647